# Односвязный список заполнение из файла

Tags: c

Есть односвязный список, данные для которого считываю из файла. Проблема в том, что после считывания из файла, все строчные значения списка равны последнему считанному значению, не могу понять в чем проблема:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct cart {
char* a;
    char* b;
    int c;
struct cart *next;
} cart;
FILE* file;
cart* head = NULL;
void push(cart **head, char* a, char* b, int c);
void readthefile(cart **head, char* a, char* b);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char* a  = (char*)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
char* b = (char*)malloc(20 * sizeof(char)); 
    readthefile(&head, a, b);
    while(head != NULL) {
            printf("%s %s %d\n", head->a, head->b, head->c);
            head = head->next;
    }
return 0;
}
void readthefile(cart **head, char* a, char* b) {
    file = fopen("1.txt", "r");
    int c;
    while(fscanf (file, "%s%s%d", a, b, &(c)) != EOF){

    //printf("%s %s %d\n", a, b, c);
            push(head, a, b, c);

    }
}
void push(cart **head, char* a, char* b, int c) {
cart *tmp = (cart*) malloc(sizeof(cart));
    tmp->a = a;
    tmp->b = b;
    tmp->c = c;
tmp->next = (*head);
(*head) = tmp;
}
```

Содержимое файла 1.txt:

```
A B 2
C D 3
E F 4
```

Comment: Из чистого любопытства: а почему вы не используете отладчик?

Comment: И ещё: воспроизводится ли проблема, если вы читаете данные не из файла, а из заранее подготовленного массива?

Comment: Пробовал, на прямую вызвать функцию добавления, и просто передать ей параметры, все работает. И в функцию после считывания  из файла приходят нормальные данные. Пишу в среде Pelles C.

Comment: Хм. Тогда и правда странно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в коде

```
void push(cart **head, char* a, char* b, int c) {
    cart *tmp = (cart*) malloc(sizeof(cart));
    tmp->a = a; // <-- здесь
    tmp->b = b; // <-- и здесь
    tmp->c = c; //
    tmp->next = (*head);
    (*head) = tmp;
}
```

Дело в том, что вы записываете в узел списка *указатели* на строки. А затем повторно используете эту же память для чтения в неё *новых* данных. В результате у вас все узлы списка ссылаются на одни и те же строки.

Попробуйте использовать `strdup` (или `_strdup` для Visual Studio).

Comment: Спасибо, за решение моей проблемы! Были мысли о том что адрес перезаписывается...

Comment: Пожалуйста! Ручное управление памятью — самый сложный аспект C.